# List Web Part opens item in classic mode and in new tab

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, web-part

I have a standard modern Team Site created in SharePoint Online. I add a new list, and add it to my home page using the OOTB List Web Part.
I finally add an item to the list.

When I click on the item through the Web Part, it opens the item in a new tab in the browser.
I would like it to be opened in the same tab, and redirect the user back to the initial page after clicking.
Is this possible? If not, is there any sample or 3rd party Web Part that might achieve this?

Also, in one list we provision using PnP, the list item is even opened in Classic mode in the new tab. Has anyone any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

In list settings, make sure the List experience is set to "New experience"
[image]

Comment: Sorry to say, this had no effect. The site is also already created as a modern site, so in theory this setting should have no effect.
I tried creating a new list on the same site, and it opens the list item with modern look. So it seems there's something "classic" with the list being provisioned using PnP.
But regardless, it still opens up the new tab. Is this customizable in any way, or by design?

Comment: There isn't any OOTB way to open the list added in other page to open in same tab

Comment: This is not good. I hope Microsoft is planning changes to this, or at least enhancements to the OOTB WebPart supporting these kind of settings.